# Confusion about Fractional Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I'm reading an expository paper by Keith Conrad (Ideal Factorization) and there is a step I don't quite follow.

Let $K$ be a number field, and $I$ be a fractional ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $\tilde{I} = \lbrace x \in K : xI \subset \mathcal{O}_K\rbrace$. We want to show that $\tilde{I}$ is itself a fractional ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$. It's easy to see that $\tilde{I}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_K$-module but Conrad goes on to say that $\tilde{I}$ is a fractional ideal by the following reasoning.

> Pick a non-zero $y \in I$. Then $y\tilde{I} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ and so $\tilde{I} \subset (1/y)\mathcal{O}_K$. Therefore $\tilde{I}$ is a submodule of a finite free $\Bbb Z$-module, and so $\tilde{I}$ is a finitely generated $\Bbb Z$-module, and hence finitely generated as an $\mathcal{O}_K$ module.

I don't understand why $y\tilde{I} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$. Is it obvious? The element $y$ is an element of a fractional ideal and $x$ is an element of $K$ so it isn't obvious to me that the products of all the elements of $\tilde{I}$ with a non-zero element of $I$ should be in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: Yes it is obvious. $y \overline{I} \subset I \overline{I} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$ by definition of $\overline{I}$. And remember $\mathcal{O}_K$ is by definition the largest subring of $K$ that is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module (integrally closed..)

Comment: @reuns Cheers :)

Comment: If you have to ask, it's not obvious. At least not by a normal person's definition of the word.